# c# error about array (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Tags: c#, arrays

error image https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC5sE.png

i want to add data to dataz but found error when build

This my code

```
int i = 0;
string[][,] dataz = null;
conn.Open();

OleDbCommand db = conn.CreateCommand();
db.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
db.CommandText = "select name,img from [building] order by id asc ";

OleDbDataReader oReader = db.ExecuteReader();


while (oReader.Read())
{

        string name = oReader.GetString(0);
        string img = oReader.GetString(1);
        dataz[i] = new string[,] { { "name", name }, { "img", img } };
        i++;

}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Editing your question doesn't mean that it's not a duplicate...

Answer (score -2):

Use Linq To SQL

```
var data = 
    ctx.Buildings.OrderBy(x => x.id).Select(x => new { x.name, x.img }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Please elaborate why your answer is the solution to the problem.

Comment: The problem can be solved at different levels. I hope my solution will interest novice programmer, he learns with Linq That SQL or another ORM